# "Undefined control sequence" at beginning of any simple document

Tags: pdftex

Very new to Tex. Trying to get the most basic doc to work. Not matter what I do I always get an "Undefined control sequence" at line 1 of my document. As of now, I am only trying to build the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a test of the article
\end{document}
```

Full error is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./example.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
?
```

I have tried many other variations, including `\usepackage` directives that people mentioned - nothing every varies.

Comment: you need to use `pdflatex` not `pdftex` as the command to process your document.

Comment: +1 for complete example document and complete posting of error message (I wish everyone would do that:-)

Comment: "pdflatex" worked. Figuring out what/where/how to install was the less obvious part.

Comment: @Brad: TeXlive 2015 is available since about seven weeks, please consider to update. Is the topic solved now?

Comment: BTW, the most basic TeX that work with `pdftex`  is " `This is a test of the article \bye`",  but surely you want to start to play with LaTeX, not with plain TeX.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I too used `pdftex` instead of `pdflatex`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Each `LaTeX` document has basically this structure (which will not run though, since `packageA` and `packageB` are not valid packages (as far as I know!)

```
\documentclass{book}  % Replace book with some other class 

\usepackage{packageA}  % Load package named packageA
\usepackage{packageB}  % Load package named packageB

% Some other definitions to follow, i.e. user defined counters, lengths

\begin{document}
% Typesetting and other code
\end{document}
```

This can't be compiled with `pdftex` -- Use either `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex` for this.

Each of the commands above are `LaTeX` format additions, completely unknown to `pdftex` and its variants, so `pdftex` stops at `\documentclass` already.

Packages always must have the ending `.sty`, so e.g. `hyperref.sty`, it's sufficient to use `\usepackage{hyperref}` then.

It is possible to load code contained in other files than having the `.sty` extension by saying `\input{foo}` (`foo.tex` is another ASCII - file then) basically at any position in the document, either in the preamble or in the document body.

The part including `\documentclass` downto `\begin{document}` is called preamble, the part between `\begin{document}...\end{document}` is the document body. Typesetting is allowed in the body only. Preamble commands like `\documentclass`, `\usepackage` etc. **mustn't** be used in the body.

The above document would not do anything so far (depending on the packages of course)

Comment: Upvoted. I've added full installation instructions and `pdftex` and `pdflatex` demos for Linux Ubuntu [in my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1473017/327339). Your answer helped me figure out I needed to use `pdflatex`.