# ! Undefined control sequence. \documentclass

Tags: errors

I got  ERROR in LATEX like this
 Error ! Undefined control sequence. \documentclass
 anyone is there give me response quickly ...
I hope give the answer in detail because i already read more answer about this error

Comment: Run `pdflatex` and not `pdftex`. That means: Use LaTeX. Not TeX.

Comment: Closely related: [“Undefined control sequence” at beginning of any simple document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258617/134144)